# Constructing a "sheaf of vector fields" for a flasque sheaf of $k$-algebras

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, sheaf-theory, ringed-spaces

- Let $k$ be a field. We require all algebras to be associative and commutative. Unital algebra morphisms are required to preserve the multiplicative identity.
- Let $\mathcal{O}$ be a sheaf of unital $k$-algebras on a topological space $X$.

  Assume $\mathcal{O}$ is flasque/flabby.
- Definition: Given open $U\subset X$ and $D : \mathcal{O}(U)\rightarrow \mathcal{O}(U)$
  a $k$-linear derivation,

  we say $D$ is "*well-behaved*" if:

  for any $f,g \in U$
  and any open $V \subset U$,
  if $f|_V = g|_V$
  then $D(f)|_V = D(g)|_V$.
- Now if we define
  $$
  \mathcal{F}(U) = \{ D \in \mathrm{Hom}_{k\text{-Vect}}(\mathcal{O}(U),\mathcal{O}(U))\,|\, D\text{ is well-behaved derivation} \}
  $$
  this should produce a sheaf of $k$-Lie algebras, with Lie bracket being the object-wise commutator.

  The restrictions are defined for $U \supset V$ by $D|_V(h) = D(\tilde{h})|_V$
  where $\tilde{h} \in \mathcal{O}(U)$ is chosen such that $\tilde{h}|_V = h$;
  such $\tilde{h}$ exists since $\mathcal{O}$ is flasque;
  and $D(\tilde{h})|_V$ is independent of the choice of lift $\tilde{h}$ because $D\in\mathcal{F}(U)$ is well-behaved.

---

My questions are:

1. Are the above constructions and assertions valid?
2. Can we view $\mathcal{F}$ as a "sheaf of vector fields" on $X$?

   For example, if $X$ is a smooth manifold with $\mathcal{O}$ the sheaf of smooth real functions, then the above should reproduce the sheaf of sections of $TX$. (The "well-behaved" condition should always hold in this case?)

Comment: Just as in your last question, you are trying to produce something which you should not expect to be a sheaf using $\mathcal{Hom}$ in this manner. How are you making $\mathcal{F}$ into a presheaf, much less a sheaf?

Comment: @MarkSaving The restrictions are defined as stated in the 4th bullet in my post. If I'm not mistaken, this defines a presheaf satisfying the sheaf condition. The "restriction", as defined above, of a "well-behaved" derivation should give another one.
However, I'm not sure if this is better handled using sheaf internal homs; my knowledge of sheaf machinery is very little.

Comment: Your method does indeed work; sorry for not reading more thoroughly before commenting. I have added some more details in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition does produce a valid sheaf. There is another way of doing this which is conceptually more elegant. $\DeclareMathOperator{Hom}{Hom}$

Consider the sheaf $G(U) = \{D \in \Hom(\mathcal{O}|_U, \mathcal{O}|_U) \mid $ for each $V \subseteq U$, $D(V)$ is a $k$-linear derivation$\}$. In the internal logic of sheaves, we are constructing the “set” $G = \{D : \mathcal{O} \to \mathcal{O} \mid D$ is a $k$-linear derivation$\}$, which of course can become a Lie algebra.

Note that $G$ can be constructed regardless of whether $\mathcal{O}$ is flasque. However, when $\mathcal{O}$ is flasque, we see that $G$ and $\mathcal{F}$ are isomorphic.

For consider the natural transformation $\theta : G \to \mathcal{F}$ defined by $\theta_U(D) = D(U)$. It is easy to see that $\theta$ is well-defined; if we have $D \in G(U)$, then we see that for all $f, g \in \mathcal{O}(U)$, for all $V \subseteq U$, if $f|_V = g|_{U}$, then $D(U)(f)|_{V} = D(V)(f|_V) = D(V)(g|_V) = D(U)(g)|_V$, so $D(U)$ is “well-behaved”. Now suppose we have $V \subseteq U$, $D \in G(U)$, and $f \in \mathcal{O}(V)$. Take some $f’ \in \mathcal{O}(U)$ such that $f’|_V = f$; then $\theta_U(D)|_V(f) = \theta_U(D)(f’)|_V = D(U)(f’)|_V = D(V)(f’|_V) = D(V)(f) = D|_V(V)(f) = \theta_V(D|_V)(f)$. This confirms the naturality of $\theta$.

Now I claim that $\theta$ is an isomorphism. To do this, we explicitly construct the inverse of $\theta_U$. Given $D \in \mathcal{F}(U)$, define $\eta(D)$ to be the natural transformation given by $\eta(D)(V) = D|_V$. This is a natural transformation by the definition of the restriction operator. We see immediately that $\theta_U \circ \eta$ and $\eta \circ \theta_U$ are both the identity.

So we see that $\mathcal{F}$ is just another way of constructing $G$ if we add an extra assumption - that $\mathcal{O}$ is flasque.

Now with our $G$, we can easily define the Lie bracket in the way you would expect. Given $D, E \in G(U)$, we can define $[D, E](V) = [D(V), E(V)]$ (using the ordinary Lie bracket structure on derivations). It is easy to verify the equations of Lie algebra hold here; they follow from the corresponding set-theoretic facts.

As for your second question, I’ll have to think on it a bit more.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation!